# Client connect with many servers through sockets

Tags: c, sockets, unix

Can I connect client with 4 servers? I must check witch one is acctive. But when I run my program, it works for first server. For next server, there is error: "Transport endpoint is already connected"
 My code:

```
void contact(int socket, int argc, char **argv, node **server_threads)
 {
pthread_t s;
int socketFd, newsockfd,i;
struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
socklen_t clientlen = sizeof(clientAddr);

     for(i=3;i<argc;i=i+2)
     {
         serverAddr = makeClientAddress(argv[i],atoi(argv[i+1]));
         if(connect(socketFd,(struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in))<0)
                error("connect");
     }

     while(newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &(clientAddr), &clientlen))    
     {
         printf("Server is active\n");
         insert_at_end(server_threads, NULL,NULL,&s);
         pthread_create(&s, NULL, (void*)connect_with_server,&sockfd);
     }

    void connect_with_server(void* arg){

    int* sock=(int*)arg;
        while(1)
        {
        if(read(sock,(char *)data,sizeof(int32_t[5]))<(int)sizeof(int32_t[5])) ERR("read:");
            printf("Signal from server\n");
    }
```

Comment: Close the socket before you reconnect.

Comment: "Can I connect client with 4 servers?" Of course - does your web client (browser) support having multiple tabs open to different web sites?

Comment: Why does your client call `accept()`?

Comment: `socket`, `socketFd`, `sockFd`, `newsockfd` ... hu... a lot of socket descriptor for a client. One per connection ought to be enough, at least if it was successfully initialised using a call to `socket()`.

Comment: Because in my program, server is also client and try check another server... So it must call function accept and connect...

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to many servers, but to do that you must use different FD's on your client. Once an FD is set to an Server, this FD will handle just this connection.

You must keep a vector with all FD's started and keep your program working on the vector.

And you don't need to use accept function in your code, you must just connect to the Server and after that get the FD's connection and do whatever you want.